# Display data coming from nodejs in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I'm sorry if this is a repeated question. but, I'm trying hard to figure out a way to display the data from my nodejs in html.

Following is my data.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

var data = new Array;    
data.push([1,2,3]);
data.push([4,"Test data",6]);

app.use(function (req, res) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:9000');
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.send(data)
  //next();
});

app.listen(9000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port localhost:9000!');
});
```

I want to display this data in the html page. Can anyone help with the HTML/JQuery script here? Thanks.

HTML Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
 alert('Hello');

$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:9000",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: success

});

$.get('/', {}, function(data){
// not sure it is the right code
console.log(data);
// then the code to create a list from the array (no pb with that)
});

//function jsonpCallback(data){
//    alert("jsonpCallback");
//}
    //do jQuery stuff when DOM is ready
});
</script>

    <h1>Header Text</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to set up api routes and a file serving route. Then you can call on the api method (via jQuery ajax for example) and get the response data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var data = new Array;    
data.push([1,2,3]);
data.push([4,"Test data",6]);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.send(data);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

I don't have nodejs with me right now to test this but this should give you an idea. You have to define routes. I defined .get("/") for you so every request to main url will call this function. I also set Access-Control-Origin to *. If you want to secure things a bit, serve static files from nodejs.